# SQL if statement for date range

Tags: sql, date, if-statement

Hi I was needing help with the syntax to add a condition where the current date is retrieved if today is after the 5th of each month but if its between the 1st to the 5th then it should retrieve the month before this month. Is it something you can help with please? Below is how my query is structured.

```
 Select * 
 FROM table1  
  left join  table2
       on e.ENTITY_NBR  = d.entity_nbr
     and cast(getdate() as date) between MONTH_BEGIN_DATE and MONTH_END_DATE
```

Comment: can you give me the actaual result of this query and the output you need?

Comment: Do you literally just want to include the relevant date (either today, or one month prior to today, depending on the criteria you explained) in the returned columns, or do you actually want to use that calculated date to filter the results somehow?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products have their own, non-ANSI SQL functions. Like getdate()...

Comment: What are `MONTH_BEGIN_DATE` and `MONTH_END_DATE`?  What are `e` and `d`?  None of this is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to include todays date (or the same date from last month if it's currently the 5th or earlier in the current month), then this can be done in your `SELECT` clause:

```
select
    case 
        when datepart(day,getdate()) <= 5 
        then dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) 
        else getdate() 
    end
```

If you want to actually use this date to compare to some field in your dataset, then you can include this same case expression in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put `case` _expressions_ in the WHERE clause. It's better to use regular AND/OR instead.

Comment: That's a fair point. It wasn't entirely clear whether the question asker actually wanted to use this calculated date in their `WHERE` clause, but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    Select *,
    CASE WHEN day(GETDATE()) > 5 THEN GETDATE()
    ELSE DATEADD(month,-1,getdate()) END as date
     FROM table1  
      left join  table2
           on e.ENTITY_NBR  = d.entity_nbr
         and cast(getdate() as date) between MONTH_BEGIN_DATE and MONTH_END_DATE
```

Based on a vague description of your problem this is the best I can write.

Answer (score 0):

> where the current date is retrieved if today is after the 5th of each month but if its between the 1st to the 5th then it should retrieve the month before this month.

Based on this description, you want something like this:

```
select * 
from table1 e left join
     table2 d
     on e.ENTITY_NBR = d.entity_nbr and
        (day(getdate() > 5 and datediff(month, d.date_col, getdate()) = 0 or
         day(getdate() <= 5 and datediff(month, d.date_col, getdate()) = 1)
        )
```